# webservice call keeps returning json

Tags: web-services

I'm just trying to test a very simple ajax call to a simple webservice. I'm using .net 4, iis 6. My webservice code looks like this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ABCNamespace    {
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("Hello World");
    }
}
}
```

My call looks like this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../../MyService.asmx/HelloWord",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () { alert('done'); },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }
        });
```

I'm keep getting 500 error and after taking a closer look, I'm getting a string back instead of json data. I think if correct this, it will fix my issue. However, I can't get it to return json data.

Here is a response check by invoking my webmethod

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> "Hello World" </string>
```

Note: please ignore the fact that I'm using ../../ in my url instead of resolveURL. This is just for quick simple testing purposes. I also play around with the web.config handlers and no luck. Not sure what I miss...

Comment: look at type, should be get..type: "GET"

Comment: I tried GET and no luck

Comment: I have a feeling that it may have something to do with my web.config? but as far as I know I don't have to do anything special with the web.config if I'm using .net 4

Comment: I found and fixed the issue. My ScriptHandlerFactory had the wrong version.